# c3 charts order not working in safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, d3.js, safari, c3.js

C3 charts order function for stacked bar chart is working in Chrome and Firefox, but in safari and IE, order of the data in bar is reversed.
Here is the demo

https://jsfiddle.net/shru8051/wp520y8j/

```
<div id="chart"></div>

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['MONETARY', 11340, 3259],
            ['NON-MONETARY', 12335, 18041]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['MONETARY','NON-MONETARY']
        ],
         order:function(t1,t2){return true},
    },

    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['DENTIST', 'PROGRAMMER/ANALYST']
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `order` function is incorrect:

`order:function(t1,t2){ return true }`

According to [the documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-order)

> **[data.order](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-order)**
>
> Define the order of the data.
>
> This option changes the order of stacking the data and pieces of
>   pie/donut. If null specified, it will be the order the data loaded. If
>   function specified, it will be used to sort the data and it will
>   recieve the data as argument.

For me in Chrome when hovering over bar items in tooltip continuously switch places. It is because of you `order` function always return `true`. If you want to blue rect (`Monetary`) placed over orange rect (`Non monetary`), you can simply rewrite `order` property this way:

```
order: function(v1, v2) {
  return dataOrder.indexOf(v1.id) < dataOrder.indexOf(v2.id) ? 1 : -1
}
```

Where `dataOrder` is `var dataOrder = ['MONETARY', 'NON-MONETARY'];`

Check this forks of your fiddle in Safari and IE - https://jsfiddle.net/y0qLnvv4/6/

Comment: My requirement is different, it should not be displayed in ascending order of data, order of data should not change i.e order of colors in the bar must always be same. ex: in the given example, blue color in the bar must always be on the top, no matter what the value is ..... in chrome blue color is on top of bar whereas in safari blue is displayed in the bottom of the bar

Comment: @SKRamesh Oh, now I grasp your issue, thanks for the clarification. I updated my answer and jsfiddle, check, please.

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: Hi Mikhail Shabrikov..i have got an issue now ,it is working fine in safari, but in chrome n Firefox only first data is in order(i.e top color),other colors r not in order , colors in the bar must be in same order as legend.this is my actual project : http://jsfiddle.net/vtxexeb0/ (its perfect in safari, problem is in chrome). Thank you

Comment: Yes, the previous solution was not universally and worked in the case when we have only two data items. I updated the answer, check this fiddle for your actual project - http://jsfiddle.net/vtxexeb0/2/